# Use XDocument with Visual Studio Mac .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-mac

quite strange I can't use XDocument in Visual Studio Mac (OSX Cocoa App), I even added System.Xml.XDocument nuget package... what am I missing?  thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

duh - had to add System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq to references... VS Mac doesn't do it automatically like VS Windows does.